# adding class to an element in Vuejs component modifies all instances of that component

Tags: jquery, vue.js, components, prop, lifecycle-hook

I wrote a mounted function to conditionally add and remove classes from an element in a Vuejs component. It appears that the function adds the class to the element in not only this instance of the component but in all instances of that component. Why is this? Do I need to be using refs? The greater context is a form. Each instance of this component is a form field with a floating label. The reason for adding and removing the class is to create the floating label.

It also appears that the mutableFieldContent === '' is never true even the mutableFieldContent is empty/undefined. Not sure why this is the case either.

I'm kind of new to Stack Overflow. I apologize if this should be two questions.

Thanks!

```
<template>
    <div class="form-field" id="outerdiv">
        <div class="form-field__control">
            <label for="exampleField" class="form-field__label">{{fieldLabel}}</label>
            <input id="exampleField"  v-model="mutableFieldContent" @blur="setActive(false, $event)" @focus="setActive(true, $event)"
            type="text" class="form-field__input" />
        </div>
    </div>    
</template>

<script>
import $ from "jquery";

export default {
    name: "FormField",
    props: {fieldContent: String, fieldLabel: String},
    data() {
        return {
            mutableFieldContent: this.fieldContent
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setActive(active, event) {
            const formField = event.target.parentNode.parentNode
            if (active) {
                formField.classList.add('form-field--is-active')
            } else {
                formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-active')
                event.target.value === '' ? 
                formField.classList.remove('form-field--is-filled') : 
                formField.classList.add('form-field--is-filled')
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log("this.mutableFieldContent: "+this.mutableFieldContent);
        console.log("classList of element: "+ $("#outerdiv")[0].classList);
        this.mutableFieldContent === ""?

            (console.log("fieldContent is empty"), 
            $("#outerdiv")[0].classList.remove('form-field--is-filled')):

            (console.log("fieldContent exists"),
            ($("#outerdiv")[0].classList.add('form-field--is-filled')))
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    .form-control{
        border-style: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        font-size: 20px;
        background: none;
        text-decoration-line: underline;
    }  
</style>
```

And here is where I insert the component...

```
      <div v-for="field in category.fields" v-bind:key="field.label">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col">
                                                    <div v-if="!field.haschoices">
                                                        <FormField
                                                            :fieldContent="person[field.personfield]"
                                                            :fieldLabel="field.label"
                                                        ></FormField>     
                                                    </div>
```

Comment: Well each component will go through it's own mounted lifecycle step so is each component adding the class in their respective mounted steps?  Also, I suggest learning how to [bind classes to elements](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) with Vue rather than jQuery.

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Vue like this is a bad idea. Instead of manipulating the DOM directly (the "jQuery way"), you should be binding values to the template (the "Vue way").

Comment: Thank you. After learning about $refs, I understand now that what I was doing previously - getting the element by Id and then modifying the element- will indeed undesirably mutate all instances of the component. Using a ref only mutates this instance. That did the trick and solved the first problem.